# Disable/clear automatically cache in webview…

Tags: ios, iphone, webview

I created an app for iOS. In this app I have a webview linked with my homepage. But: there is always the same content like at the first start of the app. When I change something at my homepage or any link in it it doesn't change on my iOS device. Perhaps it is saved in cache? Notice: There is always the same content in the webview although I changed something at my homepage. I think it is the cache?!

How can I disable the cache? Or better, the cache should clear automatically, per example at start of the app.

Can anybody help me please?

Here is my code in ViewContoller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation ViewController
-(IBAction)refresh:(id)sender; {

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://examle.com"]; NSURLRequest * requestURL=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; [_site loadRequest:requestURL];

}
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [self refresh:self];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Plan" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_ImageInWebView loadRequest:request];
    [_ImageInWebView setScalesPageToFit:YES];

    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Book" ofType:@"pdf"];
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_PDFInWebView loadRequest:request];
    [_PDFInWebView setScalesPageToFit:YES];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    _myBotton.layer.borderWidth =2.0f;
    _myBotton.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
}
```

Comment: try     [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache]removeAllCachedResponses];

Comment: Where to add this code?

Comment: just before refresh method ..

Answer (score 1):

I am an [iOS developer](http://www.loungelizard.com/home/ios-developer) and I would recommend you not to disable the cache completely as it will affect your app's performance adversely. You can firstly configure the cache limits using this code in application:
    DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
int cacheSizeMemory = 4*1024*1024; // 4MB
int cacheSizeDisk = 32*1024*1024; // 32MB
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cacheSizeMemory diskCapacity:cacheSizeDisk diskPath:@"nsurlcache"];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];

// ... other launching code
}
```

and then in when you need to clear the cache use the command:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses] .
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where do I have to add this code? Just the first code? What is the second code? What do the codes exactly?